# Switch UK T2 ICT Visa to T2 general

Tags: visas, uk

I'm Syrian citizen living in Dubai. My company offered to move me to UK under T2 ICT visa for 2 years with a good salary (I'm skilled IT consultant). Do I have any opportunity to switch to T2 General visa so that I can get PR and UK citizenship after 6 years?

Comment: Questions about long term migration, including work visas, belong on [expatriates.se]

Answer (score 1):

I found this from an immigration lawyer website here in the UK. I recommend you still check the official home office guidelines on converting your Tier 2 ICT to an ILR (Indefinite Leave to Remain).

“You eligibility to apply for Indefinite Leave to Remain (ILR) from a Tier 2 ICT Visa will depend upon when you first received it. If it was issued before the 6th of April 2010 then you will be eligible to use the time that you have built up on your Tier 2 ICT Visa to apply for Indefinite Leave to Remain (ILR) in the UK. If you were issued your Visa after the 6th of April 2010 then you will not be entitled to use the time that you have built up in the UK to go toward an application for Indefinite Leave to Remain (ILR).”

Hope this was helpful